# React native showing TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Context._context')

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using context API to store my user information in the state. First I tried to use the createContext in app.js and provided my value and everything worked fine. but I was getting a warning which is about required cycles. So I thought If I create the context in a different file I won't get the warning. So I created a js file called appContext.js

**appContext.js**

```
import React from "react";

export const AppContext = React.createContext({});
```

then I tried to use it in my app.js file like this

```
import Home from "./Screens/Home";
import Signup from "./Screens/Form/Signup";
import Login from "./Screens/Form/Login";
import { AppContext } from "./appContext";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function App() {
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    userName: null,
    userEmail: null,
    userPhone: {
      number: null,
      countryCode: null,
    },
    userLoggedIn: false,
  });

 return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        userState: [userInfo, setUserInfo],
      }}
    >
      {userInfo.userLoggedIn ? (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      ) : (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Drawer.Navigator edgeWidth={0} initialRouteName="Sign Up">
            <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            <Drawer.Screen name="Sign Up" component={Signup} />
          </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      )}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );


}
```

But I'm getting this error: `undefined is not an object(evaluating 'Context._context')`
[image: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'Context._context')]

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. actually, I was importing the context in my sigup.js file incorrectly.